# fetch JSON array from node to Reactjs

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch an array on my node server on `localhost:3000/users` to my react app on `localhost:3000`.
The problem is I don't getting an array on react and cannot fetch anything to my list.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  username: "samsepi0l"
}, {
  id: 2,
  username: "D0loresH4ze"
}];

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Comment out this line:
  //res.send('respond with a resource');

  // And insert something like this instead:
  res.json(arr);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And the react App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {users: []}

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/users")
      .then( (res) => res.json())   
      .then( (json) => {this.setState({users: json});});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {this.state.users.map(user =>
          <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

How can I fetch the array to react page?

and here is the error that I got when I run the npm server:
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `fetch('localhost:3000/users')`?

Comment: No, it is same @Colin

Comment: Are you sure? How could `fetch()` know what `/` is?

Comment: Seems you are receiving XML or HTML. However, it also seems weird that your React App and backend are trying to run on the *same* port: 3000. You may change one of them to another port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the endpoint for the **fetch("/users")** call

```
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('got the response');
  res.json(arr);
});
```

Also, you need to separate your front end react app from your server express which handles the request.

**You cannot have the same port which your apps are listening**. Set up different port. I.E 8000 for the front end and 8080 for the express server

**UPDATE**

I've managed to reproduced the tutorial which i think is the same you have found based from here : https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/calling-express-api-in-react-using-react-script-e19084a76a8a

There is nothing wrong with the tutorial. You have to set up the proxy part in the client/package-json

```
"proxy" : "http://localhost:3005"
```

and in the bin/www you have to set the line from

`var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');`

to

```
 var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3005');
```

finally you may need to install the **concurrently** dependency in the server package.json

finally i have attached the tree structure of the tutorial

[image]

Comment: Second point is right, but I think OP might have a `users.js` file from which they're exporting the `router.get('/')` so the way they have it is fine.